# Google Chart won't fire from external javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to place my javascript into an external file. However, it will only launch inline. The first code below is my main php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <?php require "connection.php"?>  
 <?php require "datafromphpinhere.php"?>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Taitel</title>
<link href="stylin.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>             
     </head><body>
    <div id="console">
      <div id="header"><h1>My Chart</h1></div>
      <div id="chart"></div>
      <div id="query"></div>   
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>  
<script src="jsthings.js"></script></div></body></html>
```

And on my **jsthings.js** file I have the following code:

```
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(vis);
      function vis() {
        var info = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsondata?>);
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
        document.getElementById('console'));
    var querycontrol = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
      'containerId': 'query',
      'options': {'filterColumnLabel': 'Food', 
      'width': 100}
    });
    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'PieChart',
      'containerId': 'chart',
      'options': {
        'width': 200,
        'height': 650,
        'vAxis' : {direction : -1},
        chartArea: {backgroundColor: {stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 1}},
        'legend': 'none'}});
    dashboard.bind(control, chart);
    dashboard.draw(info);}
```

I have placed a modified copy of my entire php and js because I wonder if my problem is DOM-related. The google charts functions and features as is run perfectly fine. However, for whatever reason I can only get the jsthings.js code to run inline, on my main php file. It simply fails to launch when moved to its own js file.

The goal is simply to have it launch alongside the main page as it loads.

If there are inconsistencies with the div names, please don't mind them. I likely missed some things when changing names for this question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you might be running into is not referencing the `jsthings.js`.
 Make sure the path to the fie is right.

Also check your console to see if you are running into any errors.

Comment: As much as I wish this were the case, it is not. I keep replacing the contents of `jsthings.js` with test functions `alert('foo')` and it runs. I don't know if it matters, but I am using Hostgator's code editor to do this stuff.